# When you use a sitecore <Image> tag with classes, why are the classes removed when you add an image in the experience editor

Tags: jss

When I add an image through experience editor this is the image tag I get when I inspect the source.

```
<img src="/sitecore/shell/-/media/image.jpg?h=2796&amp;iar=0&amp;w=4554&amp;la=nb-no" width="4554" height="2796" sc-part-of="field">
```

When I save, the tag is replaced with this:

```
<img width="4554" height="2796" class="HeroProdukt-bg-image scEnabledChrome" src="/sitecore/shell/-/jssmedia/image.jpg?h=2796&amp;iar=0&amp;w=4554" sc-part-of="field">
```

The code for rendering the image is :

```
<Image className="HeroProdukt-bg-image" field={image} />
```

How can I get the class on the newly added image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a workaround. Simply create a span around the image and style that like this:

```
<span className="HeroProdukt-bg-image" >
    <Image field={image} />
</span>
```

Style is then like this:

```
.HeroProdukt-bg-image img {
  ...
}
```